# GameObject[] is less accessible than (prefabs)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, monodevelop, gameobject

This basically sets up the tiles for my endless runner, the error in particular being:

> Inconsistent accessibility: field type 'gameobject' is less accessible than tilePrefabs

[image]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TileManager : MonoBehaviour {

    private Transform playerTransform;
    private float spawnZ = 0.0f;
    private float tileLength = 39.0f;
    private int amnTileOnScreen = 7;

    public GameObject[] tilePrefabs;
    // ** it is already public here **

    private List<GameObject> activeTiles;
    // Use this for initialization
    public void Start () {
        activeTiles = new List<GameObject> ();

        playerTransform = gameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;
        for (int i = 0; i <= amnTileOnScreen; i++) {
            SpawnTile ();
        }
    }  

    private void Update () {
        if (playerTransform.position.z > (spawnZ - amnTileOnScreen + 
         tileLength)) {
            SpawnTile ();
            //DisableTile ();
            DestroyTile();
        }
    }

    public void SpawnTile(int prefabIndex = - 1)
    {
        GameObject go;
        go = Instantiate(tilePrefabs[0]) as GameObject;

        // reappears here

        go.transform.SetParent(transform);
        go.transform.position = Vector3.forward*spawnZ;
        spawnZ += tileLength;
        activeTiles.Add (go);
    }

    private void DestroyTile()
    {
        Destroy (transform.GetChild (0));
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to give us the EXACT error message, including the correct case? You question states the error message uses the name 'gameobject', but there's no 'gameobject' in your code. There's also going to be a problem with your code. You're adding Instantiated objects to your private `activeTiles` list, but then destroying the object without removing the object from the `activeTiles` list. That would be a runtime issue though. In this case, a `Queue<GameObject>` would probably be better. And most definitely recycling your objects if possible (pooling).

Comment: Since we don't know what the error is it is hard to help. However, there are a few things that concern me. Firstly you use an array for tilePrfabs, but a list for activeTiles. Is there any reason why this isn't uniform?

Another thing I would recommend is rather than have an array of tile prefabs, just have a public variable for each prefab. This is how I've done it with my tile based games. Of course if you have a very large number of tiles this may not be convenient.

Answer (score 2):

Here is where the problem is located:

```
playerTransform = gameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;
```

There is a difference between `gameObject` and `GameObject`. Notice the capitalized "G" in the second one.

[`GameObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.html) is just a class used to create GameObjects.

[`gameObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component-gameObject.html) is a variable that is created from GameObject as is declared as `public GameObjects gameObject` in Unity's [`Component`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.html) class.  It's simply an instance of GameObjects.

You get access to the `gameObject` variable when your `TileManager` script derives from `MonoBehaviour`.

---

The [`FindWithTag`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html) function is in the `GameObject` class and is also declared as `static` which means that you don't need instance of GameObject to call it. You have to call it directly with the class name as

Replace

```
gameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;
```

with

```
GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;
```

Comment: once again the proof that camelcase sucks.

Comment: I like camelcase since they make it easier to read variables (different opinions from others), but yes, a problem like this one is one of the disadvantages of using them.